# Illustrator CS4 - Text Box Moves When Adjusting Bounding Box

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Adobe Illustrator CS4

I'm having a weird problem that I can't find the solution to. I make a text box manually to fill with text. I typically like to size it so the text is snug within the bounding box. Sometimes when I try to resize the text box to allow more vertical space for additional text, the text itself moves downward as if it were vertically centering. All I want is to expand the text box. I don't want to move the text that is already there.

The attached image makes what I'm talking about clear. In the picture, I am trying to expand the text box using the lower-center anchor point to add more vertical area for additional text. Usually, this would expand the text box, without disrupting the text already entered, without any problem. However, sometimes (as you can see) it moves the whole box itself slightly downward. This isn't about resizing, skewing, or distorting text on a path. It's about the text box itself moving. Please help me with this silly problem.[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a bug on your hands. Not sure anyone here will be able to reproduce / fix this for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue appears a to be software bug of too specific a nature to be usefully dealt with here.